# Bash update list of running jobs with ps

Tags: process, background-process, command-substitution

I need to run in parallel a set of computationally intensive tasks. What I was trying to do is to maintain a list of pids corresponding to the running jobs and update the list of running jobs with `ps` but I'm having troubles with the command expansion.

Basically I have a list of running jobs and want to update with `ps`. This list is saved as a string of integers (the pids) separated by spaces. The following is an example of what I want to make

```
sleep 10 &
pid=$!
running="$running $pid"
sleep 20 &
pid=$!
running="$running $pid"
sleep 30 &
pid=$!
running="$running $pid"
sleep 40 &
pid=$!
running="$running $pid"
echo "Initial list of jobs"
echo "$running"
sleep 20
echo "Jobs still running after 20 seconds"
echo $(ps -p $running -o pid= | tr -s "\n" " ")
```

but all I get is

```
Initial list of jobs 
 30815 30816 30817 30818
Jobs still running after 20 seconds
error: process ID list syntax error 
... bla bla bla ps usage...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
 running="$running $pid"
```

by

```
 running="$running,$pid"
```

In first case ps is called with

```
ps -p 12 34 45 -o pid=
```

while in the second

```
ps -p 12,34,45 -o pid=
```